# How ArrayList work with unsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, implements

I am assigned to implement my own Arraylist and Linkedlist that works very similarly to Java's provided ArrayList and LinkedList in Java.util.*, but not all of methods but some of them.

Assignment description says following:
[image]

So it sounds like that I have to implement above code into my code for every methods that I am not going to implement. However, my source code works fine without implementing above thing. I just simply do not even mention those methods that I am not assigned to implement.

My question is, I wonder why my code works fine without mentioning above requirement in assignment description. And how can I have above function with throw new exception into my code? (to satisfy that assignment requirement anyway)

**Following is my class declaration currently:**

```
public class A1ArrayList<E>
{
...
}
```

Do I have to extends or implements something from Java's list API to work with that function with exception throwing?

Comment: try `public class A1ArrayList<E> implements List<E> {...`. You can throw unchecked exceptions anywhere you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement the `List` interface.

```
public class A1ArrayList<E> implements List<E>
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use `UnsupportedOperationException` when you implement or extend interface/class that forces you to implement a given method that you don't want to provide implementation. The reason it is better to use exception instead of empty method is that you can see right away when it is getting called by another code that is not suppose to call it.

In you case if you are not implementing List (or any other interfaces) interface you don't need to provide any methods that need to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

**Update**

If you really need to make your class to be a Java `List` then you can extend `AbstractList` instead of implementing List.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are being to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` implies that your classes should either implement `java.util.List` or extend `java.util.AbstractList`.  (Check the requirements again!)

If you do this, you will find that all methods in the `List` API *have to be implemented* ... whether you mention them or not.

Note: that if your code does not either implement `java.util.List` or extend `java.util.AbstractList`, then it will not be recognized as a subclass of `List`.  That will probably cause it to fail (hypothetical) tests that your teacher is going to use for marking.

---

> Do I have to extends or implements something from Java's list API to work with that function with exception throwing?

It depends on what the (complete) requirements for your assignment say ....